# -Python- I can't get redirected link

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I want to fetch random scp info with python but it don't give redirected link. It opens a blank page that writes "Random SCP".

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = "https://scp-wiki.wikidot.com/random:random-scp"
r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)

print(r.url)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redirect link url is hiding in the JavaScript portion of the content. You can get to it by loading the content into a `soup`, using css selectors to zero in on it and extracting the final answer with a bit of string manipulation:

```
soup = soup=bs(r.content,"html.parser")
target = soup.select_one('iframe[src*="redirect"]')
print(target.attrs['src'].split("#")[1])
```

Output (in this case):

```
http://scp-wiki.wikidot.com/scp-3794
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks :)

Comment: @LinuxAndPython Glad it worked for you!